# Eclipse LogcatView buggy since upgrade to ADT r20 (Scrolls automatically, view jumps, filter slow)

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

I upgraded to ADT r20 in Eclipse Indigo and now Logcat view is quite buggy.

- Logmessages appear much slower than before.
- When switching Filters, it tales 2-8seconds until messages appear.
- When the scrollbar is at the bottom and I scroll up one wheel-click, the messages jump  backward for 1000s of messages and the scrollbar keeps on scrolling, without the view changing.

Logcat is unusable in eclipse now.

Any suggestions?
I searched through bugreports, but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: I updated issue:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20805

Answer (score 1):

> When the scrollbar is at the bottom and I scroll up one wheel-click, the messages jump backward for 1000s of messages and the scrollbar keeps on scrolling, without the view changing.

You need to explicitly activate scroll lock (using the top most right button in the log cat view) to avoid the automatic scrolling.

I think this changed only very recently as I also had a hard time yesterday when trying to read the top entry of a strack trace.

Comment: Yeah, I know this buttom, which was the PAUSE buttom in previous versions.
But it doesn't have any influence on this buggy behaviour for me.